# Showing Toast on top left corner in React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I am using React (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-toast-notifications) (React Toast Notification) library to show Toast. By default the toast is displayed on the Top-Right Corner of the screen. I want to display it on Top-Left corner for some of my pages. I looked out all the properties but didn't get it worked. Any Solution.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in the docs....

You can set a prop of PlacementType

PlacementType is equal to 'bottom-left' | 'bottom-center' | 'bottom-right' | 'top-left' | 'top-center' | 'top-right'.

Comment: I checked that.. But the PlacementType is for the transition, i.e. where it start drawing from. But it still appear at top-right corner